# DropTile in PHP or simple HTML

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net, html, .net

Features like window 8 tiles are very much in now-a-days.Drop tiles allow to ahve feature like this.Is there anyway to havr website like droptiles.com in PHP or HTML.Idid lot of googling but in vain.any one who used such thing before

**how can I get onclick JS of this site?**
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to **how can I get onclick JS of this site?**

It will be very difficult to get their code because they made that with their own concepts.Even if you will be able to their js code it will be very difficult to code that according to your needs.So better you try to implement the code with your own imagination.Try to learn advanced javascript or try jquery(which will be easy compared to js).

Best of luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit broad, there are numerous ways to implement this. However, PHP is not a relevant language for this because PHP is just server side and can't be used to change what happens on the client side.  To implement this you would need to use JavaScript.  If you don't know JavaScript, http://codecademy.com Would be a great place to learn it, or you could just google JavaScript.

Comment: I know JS.. droptiles make calls to web services.,it still uses Server side language :)